# Are there any publicly available scan document database containing text together with ticked/unticked checkboxes?

Tags: dataset, object-detection, ocr

I would like to train an optical mark recognition model (OMR) to detect and classify the ticked/unticked state of checkboxes in documents.

Does anyone know where I can have access to a publicly available scan document database containing text and ticked/unticked checkboxes?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can ask on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/